# How to attribute an icon that uses "Creative Commons (Attribution 3.0 Unported)" licensing?

Tags: android, iphone, windows-phone-7, licensing, icons

I'm about to release a mobile phone app (starting with WP7, then porting to Android, potentially to iPhone), and being a one man shop with no design skills, I was looking for free icons that are available on the web.

I came across a couple of really good ones that are licensed under "Creative Commons (Attribution 3.0 Unported)". I'm not sure how to attribute an icon... Do I do it simply in the source code of my app? Or do I need to have an "About" page on the app itself that lists the attribution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like the important part of [the license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/) is the attribution:

> **Attribution** — You must attribute the work in the manner specified by the author or licensor (but not in any way that suggests that they endorse you or your use of the work).

And the last bit:

> **Notice** — For any reuse or distribution, you must make clear to others the license terms of this work. The best way to do this is with a link to this web page.

I would have an about page on the app that includes attribution as specified by the icon creator and a link to the license.